# Yocto enable i2c and pwm using device tree method

Tags: yocto, beagleboneblack

I am very new to yocto&device tree world. I'm really having trouble understanding and implementing some concepts.
I use following layers. When i update the MACHINE to beaglebone. it is working as expected. I can use my beaglebone black.

```
 .../meta-arm/meta-arm-toolchain \
 .../meta-arm/meta-arm \
 .../meta-ti/meta-ti-bsp \
```

Now i want to enable pwm and i2c. I dont know anything about how to do that. I also want to write a driver to control my i2c chip. Also i will connect a servo motor to my pwm pin so i want to write a driver for it as well.

Considering that I am using yocto, how can I access the dts file and what should I write there to enable pwm and i2c.(Should i make some pinmux configuration also?)

How should I write the driver after activating PWM and i2c? Can you provide a tutorial for this?

Thanks

Comment: Primarily you should check in the kernel's menuconfig if i2c and pwm support are enabled - usually device tree has these enabled by default (look for `status = "okay"` in the tree). The [kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/driver-api/i2c.rst)  [documentation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/driver-api/pwm.rst) has info about the driver apis.

Comment: @skandigraun how can i check device tree in yocto. i dont know how to see its location in yocto

Comment: The device trees are part of the [kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/ti/omap), not yocto.

Comment: You can find the same also in `build/tmp/work-shared/$MACHINE-NAME/kernel-source` folder on your build machine.

Comment: @skandigraun when i run bitbake core-image-minimal, will modified files in that directory be deleted ?

Comment: Yes (well, to be more exact, your changes will be ignored. They will be reverted in this folder when you rebuild the kernel). You have to add a patch with your changes to the kernel recipe to apply your changes.